# Incorrect IOU values obtained in a segmentation task using Keras

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am measuring IOU and Dice values using a set of ground truth and predicted masks that are generated by a U-Net model. I have stored the GT and predicted masks in different folders and used custom functions to measure IOU and Dice values. The predicted masks were visually good and similar to the ground truths. These results are aptly reflected in the measured Dice value (values more than 0.95 for each combination of ground truth and predicted masks). However, the IOU values are very poor for each combination (for e.g., IOU is 0.2 when Dice is 0.95). The following is the code:

```
#load libraries
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import cv2

# custom functions:
def intersection_of_union(img1, img2):
    i = np.logical_and(img1, img2)
    u = np.logical_or(img1, img2)
    return i.sum() / u.sum()

def dice(pred, true, k = 1):
    intersection = np.sum(pred[true==k]) * 2.0
    dice = intersection / (np.sum(pred) + np.sum(true))
    return dice

filenames1 = glob.glob("project/gt_masks/*.png")
filenames2 = glob.glob("project/predicted_masks/*.png")
filenames1.sort()
filenames2.sort()

#open and write values to a csv file
csv = open('project/prediction.csv','w')
csv.write("filenames,iou,dice\n")

for f1,f2 in zip(filenames1,filenames2):
    img1 = cv2.imread(f1, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img2 = cv2.imread(f2, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_name = f2.split(os.sep)[-1]
    iou = intersection_of_union(img1, img2)
    dice_sim = dice(img2, img1, k=255)
    csv.write(img_name+','+str(iou)+','+str(dice_sim)+'\n')  
csv.close()
```

Comment: Your code looks good. There is a typo in iou function argument. It should be 'img1'. If you are using IDE I assume you had error during first run and then a rerun could use the previous run img1.

Comment: @Sudhir: Thanks, I have corrected it but that did not resolve the drastic mismatch between IOU and Dice values.

Comment: Try thresholding the masks to make them binary and then pass them to iou and dice functions.